# Data Lineage graph using D3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, data-visualization, d3tree

I want to create a similar data lineage graph using D3.js. I tried to use d3.hierarchy and tree. But those don't support multiple parents.  Also, I want to open a popup when the user clicks on the node. I will get the data from the server as a JSON.

What could be the best way to implement the below graph in D3.js?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at d3.sankey?

Comment: @SmokeyShakers Yeah, but the looks are different. I was searching for something simpler like the above image.

Comment: Take a look at this. https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/why-do-i-depend-on

Comment: Addition to my previous comment: 

Depends on: https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/dot

Also, you should consider using d3.sankey to solve your problem instead. Because I think staying within the d3 ecosystem will be easier. Of course, I am assuming you're already comfortable with d3.

Comment: @SarathSNair did you find any solution ?

Comment: @SarathSNair have you found anything, or you finalize the solution?